# Reverse IP address format with sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, command-line-interface

I have a txt file with a list of ip addresses against domain names.  eg;

```
1.1.168.192 example1.example1.net
2.1.168.192 example2.example2.net
3.1.168.192 example3.example3.net
.....
12.1.168.192 example12.example12.net
```

I can't get my sed command to change the output to;

```
192.168.1.1 example1.example1.net
192.168.1.2 example2.example2.net
192.168.1.3 example3.example3.net
....
192.168.1.12 example12.example12.net
```

sed command i'm using is

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$/\4.\3.\2.\1/'
```

using it as

```
cat filename | sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$/\4.\3.\2.\1/'
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `cat` for this. `cat` is to *concatenate* files. Use `sed -r '...' filename`, or in case the command only reads from stdin, use i/o redirection: `command < filename`

Comment: Puting `...` lines in your sample input/output helps no-one, it just makes it harder for us to test a possible solution (since we need to edit your files to remove those after we copy/paste and we sometimes aren't sure if those SHOULD be removed or if they actually do exist in your real input files) so please don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is that you've included an anchor `$` in your pattern, which tries to match the end of each line but fails. You just need to remove it:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})/\4.\3.\2.\1/' file
192.168.1.1 example1.example1.net
192.168.1.2 example2.example2.net
192.168.1.3 example3.example3.net
```

Note that I'm passing the file name as an argument to sed, thereby avoiding a useless use of cat.

Answer (score 0):

awk version

```
awk '{split(".",i,$1);printf "%d.%d.%d.%d %s\n",i[4],i[3],i[2],i[1],$2}' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r 's/([^.]+)(\.[^.]+)(\.[^.]+)\.([^ ]+)/\4\3\2.\1/' file
192.168.1.1 example1.example1.net
192.168.1.2 example2.example2.net
192.168.1.3 example3.example3.net
192.168.1.12 example12.example12.net
```